Book about an orphan girl who lives with her uncle and goes to an academy for people who have elemental powers
I'm looking for a book where a girl that lost her parents lives with her uncle. The uncle works with computers and she's still in school
She goes to an academy with people that have powers of elements. She also forms a bond with dragons and animals
It was a young adult book. There was romance in it and the academy was at a lake and vampires attack the academy.

I know it's not the House of Night series.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?

This sounds like an absolutely mad jumble of tropes.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Source-Magic-Academy-Falling-Kingdoms/dp/1072947501?

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/198846346-the-youngling?

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/211753374-aliyah-serin-and-the-box-of-zenas? No mention of a lake or vampires though.

Just to be fair, I don't think any of the examples listed so far mention the lake or the vampires... just more commenting that there are multiple works involving a young girl sent to her uncle, who runs a school for people with elemental powers.
